# Error during installing Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am installing Magento 2 on Bitnami WAMP Stack. However, soon after starting the installation it throws a list of errors and I am unable to fix this one:

> PHP Settings Check
>   Your PHP Version is 5.6.20, but always_populate_raw_post_data = 0. $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated from PHP 5.6 onwards and will be removed in PHP 7.0. This will stop the installer from running. Please open your php.ini file and set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1. If you need more help please call your hosting provider.

I have checked the php.ini but the `always_populate_raw_post_data` is already set `-1`.

I also ran php.info, it shows this:
[image]

Where's the problem?

Comment: After making your change, did you restart apache?

Comment: In your screen capture, it's set to `0`. In addition to restarting the web server, make sure you modified the correct `php.ini`. You must modify the one used by the web server, as indicated in phpinfo.php by `Loaded Configuration File`

Comment: @TallalHassan some times it might cause even though you have modified `php.ini` file So, better to restart your system and check the configuration settings by opening `http://localhost/phpinfo.php`.

Answer (score 2):

Well making changes in the `php.ini` or adding php parameter in the `.htaccess` didn't resolve my issue . 
I created `.user.ini` file on the web directory root and added this :
**always_populate_raw_post_data = -1**

Volla! issue was resolved. Let me know if you guys have any question.

Answer (score 1):

Remove semicolon(**`;`**) before `always_populate_raw_post_data` in `php.ini` file. Make sure you are changing in correct loaded configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

First of all find the path of `php.ini` configuration file. You can find `php.ini` file path by using `phpinfo()`. Once you find the path of file. Go to that path and open the file and find `always_populate_raw_post_data` and set `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1` save and restart the server.

if the issue still not gone you can add the `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1` in your `.htaccess` file which is located at the root directory of Magento then restart the server.

Now this will work.